# Android: Resuming a paused Thread after an orientation change

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a question involving threads and recovering from an orientation change.  I have seen a lot of great answers that cover threads or orientation changes, but precious few that cover both.  Here is a general scenario that covers my question:

1. App starts, contains one activity: one TextView populated with the variable "count", initially 0, a START and a STOP button.
2. Start button starts thread (using Thread), which loops incrementing
   the number and updating the TextView.
3. Stop button sets boolean flag so thread exits.
4. All variables global and volatile, Object variable signal used to control thread.

Now, what is the best way to handle an orientation change.  I am assuming that I:

- in onPause(), I call signal.wait() to pause the thread
- Save the variable "counter" on onSaveInstanceState()
- in onResume() I get "counter" back from onRestoreInstanceState()

Since onCreate()will create a new Object for "signal", how do I reestablish a link to the thread that is currenting wait()ing so that I can call notify() and resume it?

I explained this the best I could, I'll try to provide any additional information requested.

Comment: Why not just start a new thread and feed it the counter variable as an argument so it knows where to start? You correctly save the state of your Activity so that when everything restarts, you pick up where you left off. So just restart the Thread as well, and tell it where the counter left off (which you have in your savedInstanceState).

Comment: Thanks @drschultz, that will work.  I was wondering though what was the best practice.  I know that wait() and notify() work great for managing threads when the app goes in the background, I was just wondering if I could use them for an orientation change as well.

Comment: Added an answer below. Please accept it if you feel it solves your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifecycle of an Activity is designed so it can be destroyed and recreated based on system needs or user interaction, so generally speaking, any in-app operations should also be destroyed and re-created when these lifecycle changes happen. The exception would be long-running processes that run in the background apart from the Activity (like a Service).

So to answer your question, instead of trying to pause and resume the Thread, it would be better to simply restart the Thread when the Activity restarts, and feed the Thread your counter variable as an indicator of where the count left off. You are already saving this variable in your savedInstanceState, so it would simply be a matter of grabbing it at the start of your Activity, then passing it into your (new) Thread to continue counting.

Comment: Thanks again @drschultz - that's the information I was looking for.

Comment: An exception is that retained fragments can persist across a config change.  If the `Thread` (or, preferably, `AsyncTask`) lives in the fragment, it too can survive the config change.  If it finishes around the same time as the config change, it's guaranteed that any main thread callback cannot slip in between the destruction of the old activity and the creation of the new one.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede If you are retaining a Fragment and keeping track of its current Activity through (I assume) onAttach(), would that mean your thread continues to run even when your app is minimized for long periods in addition to config changes? I'm just wondering because in the case of the "counter" thread specific to this question, it seems using this method would cause your UI to "jump" to the current count since your counter has been running in the background this whole time (but not updating the paused UI thread). So in that case, a retained Fragment wouldn't work so well, correct?

Comment: Correct.  Retained fragments are just for preserving things across config changes; they may still be destroyed in the background or backstack.  To distinguish config changes from going into the background, you'd use  [`isChangingConfigurations()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29) and cancel the background processing if it's false.